# remove spaces in filenames in find output

Tags: bash, find

I want to list the size of directories under a given root (using `du -hs`) . The issue is that where the directory names have spaces the `du` command is getting each word of the name as a whole directory name.

I tried to fix this by quoting the output through `xargs` but the output is the same.

```
#!/bin/bash

root="$1"
echo "Searching in $root"
for d in $(find $root -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -i echo "'{}'")
  do 
    #
    # the root directory can take a long time so let's skip it
    #
    if [ "$d" != "$root" ] 
      then
         echo "Looking at directory $d"
         echo $(du -hs "$d")
      fi
  done
```

Comment: You don't want to remove the spaces if they're part of the filenames. The result would be a different filename. Instead you want to keep the filenames intact, but separate. But the thing is that the shell doesn't make it too easy to do that the way you hope to do it. Some mandatory reading linked.

Comment: @ilkkachu Exactly. I thought I was doing that with '{}'. Guess not. I was not trying to remove the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of exactly the issue you describe, it is [disrecommended to iterate over the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1). Instead, you should use the `-exec` option if that is available to your version of `find`:

```
find "$root" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

To exclude the `$root` directory, you can add `mindepth`:

```
find "$root" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```